# Add weekly and monthly active questions per tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

Weekly/monthly active questions is my favorite section of the SO site as it usually contains the most interesting questions. It would be nice to have the same functionality for specific tags, so I can check, for example, what are the most active Java questions this week.